# vba userform listbox editing

Tags: excel, vba

Running into some issues. Im not sure why button doesnt work. listbox populates info fine, info shows in textboxes. But when i either add data to blank textboxes or alter anything it does take my actions even proceeding to msgbox for completion.

```
Private Sub Update_Butt_Click()

Dim selValue As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim fCell As Range

    If ListBox101.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        selValue = ListBox101.List(ListBox101.ListIndex)
    Else

    Exit Sub
    
    End If

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SER")

    Set fCell = sh.Columns(1).Find(What:=selValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        fCell.Value = TextBox2.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox4.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox3.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox6.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = TextBox8.Value
        fCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBox9.Value
        
            If CheckBox1.Value Then
                fCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "NEW"
            ElseIf CheckBox2.Value Then
                fCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "OLD"
            ElseIf CheckBox3.Value Then
                fCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Spare"
            Else
                fCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
            
     End If
     MsgBox "Update Complete."
     
     Else
        MsgBox "Not Complete"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you possibly calling your Sub Update_Butt_Click in your code. This e.g. would ignite the event call for TextBox1: 
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Update_Butt_Click
End Sub